# Cakephp Model Rule

Tags: cakephp, model

I read from the cakePhp documentation , they only allow one rule per field. 
However If my field require unique Date and must be date format.  How should I place them ?
Current Code

```
    <?php
    App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

    class EventDate extends AppModel {
         //public $useTable = 'eventdate';
         public $primaryKey = 'event_date_id'; //I still need for  Delete

         public $validate = array(
           'event_date'  => array(
               'rule' => array('date','ymd'), 
               'message' => 'Enter a valid date in YY-MM-DD format.',
               'required' => true,
               'allowEmpty' => false
           )
// ,'event_date'  => array(
//               'rule' => 'isUnique'
//           )
         );



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no restriction on the number of rules a field can have in CakePHP. You can provide an associative array of rules for a specific field like this:-

```
public $validate = array(
    'event_date' => array(
        'format' => array(
           'rule' => array('date','ymd'), 
           'message' => 'Enter a valid date in YY-MM-DD format.',
           'required' => true,
           'allowEmpty' => false
        ),
        'unique' => array(
            'rule' => 'isUnique',
            'message' => 'This date already exists'
        )
    )
);
```

Just remember to make sure your array indexes are unique.

The array indexes for the individual rules (*e.g.* `format` and `unique` in the example code) can be anything, but make them descriptive to the rule being defined.

Comment: Thank , This work for me . 
However now the message unable to display when I enter wrongly. 
How to resolve this problem ?

Comment: @beginnerK glad this has worked for you (please consider accepting this as the correct answer). As for the issue with displaying the error message this should perhaps be asked as a new question as it isn't directly related to your original question. :-)